# using 32 bit SQL server ODBC on 64 bit system

Tags: sql-server-2005, odbc, 32bit-64bit

Microsoft has a SQL server either as 32 bit or 64bit, however the 64bit contains both 32bit **AND** 64 bit.

are there any MSI packages containing the 32 bit **AND** 64 bit version of the ODBC connector ?

i.e. the install package decides by itself which version to install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MSI is not very good at providing a single installer that works for both 32-bit and 64-bit systems. The 32-bit installer will not be able to write to the locations where the 64-bit files should be stored, and the 64-bit installer will not start on a 32-bit system.

Comment: ok, well how about an exe?. I see MSSQL 2005 express has a dual pack (SQLExpr64.exe) which contains both SQL server for 32 and 64bit computers

Comment: Applying this to your original question: "are there any...?" I actually don't know, but I guess there aren't. It would be possible to write a 32-bit wrapper, though, which launches the proper MSI installer depending on the target system.